# Do the Tolkien elves need to eat to survive?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, elves

On the one hand, they are physically very similar to humans, and the only crucial difference is that they don't age or fall ill. This, as well as frequent mention of food being eaten by elves, gives the idea that they do need to eat. On the other hand, Tolkien mentions elves that had been lost in the ice fields on their journey from Valinor to the Middle-Earth, and he speculates that they still wander there being lost. As there is practically no food to be found there, this seems to suggest that elves don't need food to survive.

Comment: Interesting question. My first instinct would be to suggest that not eating would weaken the *hröa* and make it easier for the *fëa* to consume it; not sure if canon bears that out though

Comment: One of Feanor's son's, Maedhros was hung by one hand from a precipice for 30 years by Morgoth and lived.  Hard to think there were a lot of food deliveries there.

Comment: @Oldcat - Morgoth is messed up enough to feed him so he'll linger for as long as possible.

Comment: See the update to my answer.  It is absolutely certain that Elves can, and sometimes did, starve to death.

Comment: "No food there"? Um... walruses, seals, etc.?

Comment: @Oldcat [Húrin](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/H%C3%BArin) was similarly put up in a seat on Thangorodrim for 28 years or so.   So whatever was keeping Maedhros alive, there's no evidence that being an Elf had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems so, but there is no clear evidence either way.  *The Silmarillion* does hint that Elves can starve and die of extreme cold, and that perhaps some did while crossing the Helcaraxe.  The "[Ask Middle-earth](http://askmiddlearth.tumblr.com/post/41746370963/how-do-elves-die)" blog covered this.

> Tolkien states right out that “the Elves die not till the world dies, unless they are slain or waste in grief (and to both these seeming deaths they are subject).” So possible elf deaths fall into two categories: those that are slain, and those that die of grief...
>
> **Though nothing is said about it directly, it’s also suggested that elves could die of starvation or extreme cold. There’s a few references made to this in The Silmarillion, though never of an elf actually dying of these causes. Either way, it’d take some serious starvation or extreme cold to do it, as elves are much much hardier than men.**
>
> As for the “waste in grief” option, that’s a bit more complicated, just because it’s vague (typical for Tolkien.) Luthien, when Beren died (the first time), was said to die of grief and broken heart. But then there’s the interesting case of rape. It’s said in “Laws and Customs of the Eldar” that, in the case of rape “one so forced would have rejected bodily life and passed to Mandos.” The only way to avoid this was to travel to Valinor immediately, like Celebrian did. So it seems to me that when something horrible (like a broken heart or rape, based on the examples Tolkien gives us) happens elves can literally lose the will to live, and so they die.

It seems likely that an Elf wouldn't starve very quickly, though - the Elf Voronwë spent seven years lost at sea and didn't starve;  although we might assume that he had plenty of fish to eat, the story (in *Unfinished Tales*) never says so.

Elves are extremely concerned about preserving and healing the world, so when we read about them hunting (which we do, fairly frequently), it is almost impossible to imagine them doing so unless they need to eat to survive.

## **Update**:

It appears that at least two Elves are known to have starved to death: the twin brothers Elurín and Eluréd.  They were the sons of Dior, who was in turn the son of Beren and Lúthien.  The sons of Fëanor attacked Dior's kingdom, killed Dior, his wife, and many others, and sent the boys into the woods to starve.  Maedhros, one of the less horrible sons of Fëanor, later repented this act, and spent quite a bit of time trying to find and rescue the boys, but to no avail.  Christopher Tolkien has confirmed that they died shortly after being sent out, when they were only 7 years old.

Comment: It would have to be extreme cold, Legolas isn't bothered at all by the cold on the misty mountain passes at all.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith - the others didn't suffer from frostbite or hypothermia, either, though.  It was unpleasantly cold on the mountain, but not unsurvivable.

Comment: Also, Boromir was too stupid to realize that Frodo was better off under the snow than on top of it.  Snow is an excellent insulator.

Comment: The hobbits would have died without the men, Tolkien makes that clear in the text.

Comment: That means that hobbits are easier to kill than men, dwarves, and elves.  Not really relevant here.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith - I perused the text of Fellowship, and I don't see any reason to believe that Tolien thought the hobbits would have died if they hadn't retreated from the mountain pass.  Boromir believed it, but Tolkien himself?  I'm not sure.  Boromir's judgement isn't really reliable, since he didn't know that Frodo would be warmer under the snow than above it.  He actually dug Frodo out of a snowdrift, when the snowdrift would have kept Frodo relatively warm and cozy, because snow is an excellent insulator.

Comment: I think you are confusing building a snow cave with being covered in snow.

Comment: Either one would work. I've done the sled dog thing while camping - just wiggle your way under the snow and go to sleep.  As long as your body heat doesn't melt the snow, you're better off under snow than on top of it.

Comment: There's further in-universe evidence that they actually do eat and are susceptible to starvation. During the Sundering of the Elves, where the Eldar took the great journey to Valinor, Yavanna gave them the gift of special corn, which is used to produce Lembas Bread, said to fill up a _man_ from one bite. I'd assume from this statement that an elf probably needs _more_ food than a man to fill themselves up. There's no indication how susceptible they are to starvation, but based on this evidence I'd safely say it's a "thing".

Comment: Surely they can starve, but it is not sure, that the losses of Fingolfin while crossing Helcaraxe were caused by the cold or starvation. If some elves would fell between two pieces of grinding ice, they would be crushed, which would count as slaying them. (like other physical injuries.)  The same holds for Elurin and Elured, might the beasts of the wilderness have eaten them.

Comment: In _The Hobbit_, we also have the steward and gaoler of the Woodland Elves getting drunk and falling asleep, giving Bilbo the opportunity to get the Dwarves out of their cells and into the barrels, which previously had been packed with provisions. Fili was put off apples because of the smell...

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

When discussion the nature of death of plants and animals, Tolkien says that elves will kill animals and plants for substance, and that while they may not like to do so, it is "their nature to be fed" and that they "have a right to live". So they need to eat to surivive.

> Some of the Eldar[=elves] (and some Men) eschew the slaying of *kelvar*[=animals] to use their bodies as meat, feeling that these bodies, resembling in different degrees their own, are in some way too near akin. (Yet none of the Eldar hold that the eating of flesh, not being the flesh of the Incarnate and hallowed by the indwelling of the *fëa*[=soul], is sinful or against the will of Eru.) But even so they must kill and eat *olvar*[=plants] or die; **for it is their nature to be fed, as to their *hröar*[=body], by living things corporeal, and things have a right to live according to their nature.** Yet violence is done to the *olvar* (which have a kinship with the bodies of the Incarnate, be it remote), and these are denied the fulfilment of their own lives and final shapes. Therefore we must hold that the Incarnate belong by nature to Arda Marred and to a world in which death, and death by the violence of others, is accepted. Neither Elves nor Men eat willingly things that have not died by violence.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "Death"</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Frodo says this after being rescued in Cirith Ungol

> “No, they [orcs] eat and drink, Sam The Shadow that bred them can only mock, it cannot make: not real things of its own. I don't think it gave life to the orcs, it only ruined them and twisted them; and if they are to live at all, they have to live like other living creatures."

While it's not completely definitive, this strongly suggests Frodo believes Elves need to eat. He's spent months in Elven settlements and even more time with Legolas in particular, so there's a good chance he'd know.

Comment: For the contrary people like myself who offer the alternate opinion that Elves are not living, I bring this quote from Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age: "All living things were divided in that day, and some of every kind, even of beasts and birds, were found in either host, save the Elves only. They alone were undivided..."

Comment: at a stretch it could maybe be read another way, but I'd say the key part of this quote is "All living things [...] save the elves only".